# handling multiple java projects, each with its own set of web pages into a single web project that has web.xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web.xml

I have the following problem at hand.

Present module structure of my project

```
Module 1
--src/main/java...
--src/main/resources
--src/main/webapp
-----with some web pages

Module 2
--src/main/java...
--src/main/resources
--src/main/webapp
-----with some web pages
```

Then i have the web module that has the deployment descriptor.

```
Web-module
--src/main/webapp
-----------WEB-INF/web.xml
```

I am using spring to manage all the beans. When i create a war file for my project and when it is deployed on the server, i want a way to access all the webpages using a defined URL. Not sure how to achieve that in spring mvc. Each module has its own set of Controllers that contain the RequestMapping.
Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate what's the reason for this packaging?

Comment: reason is that traditionally its not a webapp and is a regular java app, but i am adding new html pages to each module and i do not want to add them in the webmodule just for maintaining the module level consistency to ensure that a module will have only the webcontent relevant to it.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295049/criteria-for-flagging-an-off-topic-question